# How do you say this: git push -f origin sourcebranch:targetbranch

Tags: git

`git push -f origin sourcebranch:targetbranch`

I know what this command does.

- git: This is a git command
- push: I am doing a push, possibly even a force -f
- origin: This is on the server?
- sourcebranch: From the source branch
- targetbranch: to the target branch

But that doesn't seem right.  Because if I don't first pull `sourcebranch` locally, it doesn't work as expected.  So I'm really saying; "Push my local `sourcebranch` into the remote `targetbranch`"?

I think it's the placement of the term `origin` that throws me off.  To me it seems more correct (in English) to say: `git push localBranch : origin targetbranch` ?

TLDR; What is the significance of the order of the terms, specifically related to `origin`, which seems like a lie to me.

Answer (score 2):

> origin: This is on the server?

More accurately, `origin` is called a "remote". You can see the details by doing `git remote -v`. Usually a remote is associated with a URL on a server somewhere on the internet, but it can also be a file path to another directory on your local filesystem.

> So I'm really saying; "Push my local sourcebranch into the remote targetbranch"?

Yes, this is exactly correct. `sourcebranch` must be a local branch and `targetbranch` is a remote branch.

> I think it's the placement of the term origin that throws me off. To me it seems more correct (in English) to say: git push localBranch : origin targetbranch ?

I see your confusion. I rarely use this exact syntax because I use the same name for the source branch and target branch. I almost always use the shorthand for this situation: `git push origin branch`. The only reason to use the long-hand form you are asking about is if the names of the local source branch and the remote target branch are different. It is easy to avoid that situation, so you can pretty much ignore this syntax on a practical basis.

> What is the significance of the order of the terms, specifically related to origin, which seems like a lie to me.

The order is because `git` says so. You can read more details about the order and meaning of these arguments by doing `git help push`.

Comment: Lol, that's essentially the answer; "because `git` says so".  Was hoping it wouldn't be, but that may be what we have to work with.